# Why would deleting my ASP.NET MVC 5 application folder and redeploying speed up my sluggish site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 application running on Windows Server 2012 on IIS 8.

Every so often my site gets ridiculously sluggish to the point where it takes at least 5 seconds just to load the basic About page. It tends to feel as though it's running in Debug mode, even though my deploy process is automated, so I'm not accidentally deploying in Debug mode, and I can find no signs that it's in Debug mode. I've sometimes wondered if it's a memory issue, but I don't see the server memory getting out of control. I've also wondered if it's something weird with IIS settings such as Application Pool recycling (or something to that effect). I've been dealing with this issue for over a year, not knowing where to look next. I have MiniProfiler running in my development and staging environments, so I'm pretty familiar with the performance of my various site pages etc. Also, I have another web app on the exact same IIS server that doesn't seem to suffer from the same problem. The only difference I can think of between the 2 is that for one site I use Ninject for dependency injection, but I don't for the other site.

I'm really at a loss, but the only "cure" when the site gets bogged down is to completely delete the application files for the site and redeploy. This does the trick every time and then the site will act snappy again (loading the About page in under 1 second). I seem to have to repeat this ritual every week or 2, or at least once a month (whenever I notice the site is at a crawl).

Comment: I'm very sorry to say this, but your question is not suited for Stack Overflow, because it is very broad and vague. Answering your question would just be guessing, because there could be a million reasons why your site gets slow over time. My advice would be to run your application in a test environment to simulate this problem. Then gradually cut out features and functionality until the problem disappears. If you located the problem, but can’t figure out why this is happening, this is when you can post a question at SO showing the minimum amount of code that reproduces the issue. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I was just curious to see if this problem rang a bell with anyone. I'll try not to post such questions in the future.